# how can i set convolution neural network's filter coefficient

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm studying "Convolution Neural Network (CNN)" now.

I tried to understand the filter layer of CNN.

I understood the process of CNN but i have a question about filter layer's coefficient.

The question is, how can i set the "Coefficients of Filter"?

Do i have to set it random and adjust it by training process?

Or can i set it what i want?

In the book what i studying just shows the output of filter layer and

nothing mention about how to set the coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coefficients of the filter are more commonly known as its weights.

The best method of initializing these coefficients is still a subject of study but there is nothing from stopping you using any process of your choice.

As you have said the coefficients are a parameter that is learned and updated by the training process but can be "frozen" if you want to retain a specific set of coefficients in a certain layer.